# Eagle Library Missing Micro b Connector?

Tags: connector, eaglecad, cad

I'm not sure if this post belongs here or in another community but here we go. I'm working with Eagle cad (pcb) and i'm looking through the libraries and I couldn't find a single **MICRO** b usb connector. I found a **MINI** b connector but I truly require a MICRO b connector for my design. Has anybody found one? I need one specifically for this [Connector](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/USB-Connectors_Amphenol_10118193-0001LF_10118193-0001LF_C132562.html)

Comment: Create your own library then. :-)  It's not hard. Do check the Sparkfun Eagle library though; they've got a bunch of stuff there, microUSB most likely too.

Comment: This kind of question is better suited for our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Comment: You really should almost always make your own footprint for connectors like this. Every vendor has their very own mounting scheme so the footprints are always slightly different.

Comment: I agree with @LosFrijoles. I ***always*** make my own libraries. You won't be sorry that you did.

Comment: I also agree with the creation with the footprint, even when you are not (and not interested in) paying a monthly license for thousands of libraries you are neither actually interested in having... By the way, you can use the dimensions shown [here for the Allegro footprints](http://www.referencedesigner.com/tutorials/allegro/footprint_216.php)

Comment: @Brethlosze Thank you for the link, and to the rest does anybody know how to get started with making my own libraries?

Comment: @Nathan  Here's the [official tutorial](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/library-basics-part-1-creating-first-package-autodesk-eagle/).  In addition, if you search the webs for *eagle custom library tutorial*, you'll get a dozen more tutorials and videos.

Comment: I think it is the best path for most PCB CAE. You shouldn't remake more than 10 libraries per project....

Answer (score 2):

I found this one online that seems to be very similar to the one you posted. I'm testing it against the ones I can source here locally too:

https://github.com/snakeye/eagle-lib/blob/master/connectors/microusb.lbr

If you need ones with surface mounted supports instead:

https://github.com/dvdnhm/Maker-Tools-Eagle-Libraries/blob/master/MicroUSB.lbr

I think these two should fit the common ones you find in the stores.

Comment: Thanks, this still helps even tho this thread is 5 months old